# travel pass for Copenhagen

Tags: public-transport, europe, denmark, copenhagen

I am planning to travel to Copenhagen for 5 days and am looking for a day pass.

https://dinoffentligetransport.dk/citypass

Are all the main touristy attractions covered in the **City Pass Small** or not? I am planning to visit these places:

- Airport
- Tivoli Gardens
- Nyhavn
- Superkilen Park
- Christiania Art Gallery
- King's Garden
- Frederik's Church
- Amalienborg Palace
- Rosenburg Castle
- Reffen Street Food Market

Would the Small pass suffice or will I have to opt for the **Large** one?

Comment: Christiania Art Gallery, Reffen Street Food Market, Frederik's Church will not covered under City Pass Small and all the tourist attraction are not covered under City pass small because they are all covered by city pass large.

Comment: @pujadev Wrong. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the places you listed (incl. the airport) can be reached by public transport with the City Pass **Small**, because it covers the entire city of Copenhagen (+ several other adjacent municipalities).

A City Pass **Large** would only be necessary if you intended to visit locations farther away, such as Roskilde or Helsingor.

Source: https://dinoffentligetransport.dk/en/tickets/day-passes/city-pass-english/

However, the Copenhagen City Pass is only for public transport. It doesn't provide free or discounted access to attractions that charge admission fees. If you're interested in that, get a **[Copenhagen Card](https://www.copenhagencard.com/)**